# facebook like button not implemented correctly

Tags: facebook-like, required

i have implemented fb like button using iframe code

when i click like button it increases count on the current page but count not on fb account for which it is made

& when someone likes it like automatically add some comments on the person's profile who liked it. how to change that

Thanks

my code is this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>IE Guild Technologies</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="IE Guild" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ieguild.in" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IE Guild Technologies" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="236267259748081" />
```

& iframe code

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fieguild.in&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21"
                            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 100px;
                            height: 21px; background-color: Transparent;"></iframe>
```

Comment: add the code here so that we can find the error.

Answer (score 0):

the counts are for specifically http://www.ieguild.in, and not http://www.ieguild.in/default.html or http://www.ieguild.in/index.php, so when you look at the like counts, be sure you know the actual URL being liked. Also, you're not asking the user to like your app "fb:app_id" content="236267259748081", just the url you specified.  So if you want to have a user like your app, then you need to change the like code to point to the following url `https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=236267259748081` (and of course publishing your app page too would help)